# How create a specific space between an element and it pseudo-element "::before" ? CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to create this corner in the top-left of my title:
[image]

The problem is that I didn't find the way to decale the title from the corner.

Could you help me pls ?

This is my code:

```html
<h2 class="title_project_details">{project.name}</h2>
```

```css
.title_project_details{
    margin-bottom: 15px;

    font-family: Poppins-semi-bold;
    font-size: 29px;
    color: #210B41;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.title_project_details::before{
    border-left: 3px solid #310C50;
    border-top: 3px solid #310C50;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
}
```

```css
    .title_project_details{
        margin-bottom: 15px;

        font-family: Poppins-semi-bold;
        font-size: 29px;
        color: #210B41;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    .title_project_details::before{
        border-left: 3px solid #310C50;
        border-top: 3px solid #310C50;
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<h2 class="title_project_details">{project.name}</h2>
```

My actual result:
[image]

Thanks in advance !

Comment: added codesnippet and fixed attribute `className` which should be just `class`

Comment: Do you want that the `h2` is place as if there is no corner present, and add that corner without moving the `h2`. Or do you want the corner to be "part" of the `h2` which would result into an offset on that `h2` as soon as the corner is added?

Comment: you can simply use absolute value for your pseudo-element and then change the position easily using the top-left-right-bottom property.

Comment: Try adding `margin-bottom: 1rem;` to your pseudo element `::before`

Answer (score 1):

Try positioning the elements set relative for the title and set `absolute` for the `::before`

```css
.title_project_details{
    margin-bottom: 15px;

    font-family: Poppins-semi-bold;
    font-size: 29px;
    color: #210B41;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 3px 18px
}

.title_project_details::before{
    border-left: 2px solid #310C50;
    border-top: 2px solid #310C50;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  left: 0;
    width: 30px;
}


body {margin: 20px;}
```

```html
<h2 class="title_project_details">project.name</h2>
```

Add padding if you want space (I saw space in the reference image you showed there)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use absolute positioning for ::before, for me it looks like your desired result. u might tweak with top and left properties.

```css
    .title_project_details{
        margin-bottom: 15px;
        position:relative;
        font-family: Poppins-semi-bold;
        font-size: 29px;
        color: #210B41;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    .title_project_details::before{
        border-left: 3px solid #310C50;
        border-top: 3px solid #310C50;
       position: absolute;
       left: -6px;
       top: -1px;
        content: '';
        display: inline-block;
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
    }
```

```html
<h2 class="title_project_details">{project.name}</h2>
```

Comment: The css shown only appears to work, but the corner is not really attached to the position of the `h2` element and would fail if text is added above.

Comment: true, therefore the wrapping h2 needs to be position:relative, look at my update it seems to work good :)